# Error FileUriExposedException al abrir PDF desde carpeta assets en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, pdf

Estoy intentando abrir un PDF desde la carpeta assets de mi proyecto usando la app por defecto de lector de PDF de Android, pero recibo un error de tipo FileUriExposedException. Tengo esta función, que copia el archivo de la carpeta assets a la memoria del dispositivo:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copyFile(`in`: InputStream, out: OutputStream) {
val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
var read: Int
while (`in`.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read)
}
}
```

Y esta función que abre el PDF mediante un intent, pero se produce el error en la línea starActivity(i)

```
fun copyReadPdfFromAssets(pdfName: String){
val assetManager: AssetManager = assets

val inn: InputStream
val out: OutputStream

val file = File(filesDir, pdfName)

try{
    inn = assetManager.open(pdfName)
    out = openFileOutput(file.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    copyFile(inn, out)

    inn.close()
    out.flush()
    out.close()
}catch (e: Exception){
    Log.e("CopyReadPDFFromAssets", e.toString())
}

val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
val filePath: String = "file://" + filesDir + "/" + pdfName
val miUri: Uri

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    miUri = Uri.parse(filePath)
} else{
    miUri = Uri.fromFile(File(filePath))
}

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
i.setDataAndType(miUri, "application/pdf")
startActivity(i) // Aquí se produce el error
}
```

Y este es el error al completo:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.example.pdf/files/cons.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1960)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9885)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9839)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.copyReadPdfFromAssets(MainActivity.kt:79)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:36)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$tGt1fi2HeFZw7d_eZTjofohhZ5w(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.pdf.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas `targetSdkVersion` 23 o superior tienes que utilizar FileProvider.

Ejemplo:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, f));

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(i);
```

Para más información: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: Gracias, con tu ayuda e investigando un poco lo he conseguido. Un saludo.

Comment: Como se usa Fileprovider, considera agregar un ejemplo, revisa lo que se indica acerca de los enlaces [answer].